# What is Rails' migration equivalent to MySQL's 'double' datatype?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I can't seem to figure this one out by searching Google.

I have an existing database which has some columns with the type of `double`, what would I write in my rails migration to create an equivalent column type? It's a relatively old database and there maybe a more suitable datatype to use completely, but I wanted to see what others thought.

I was going to use the type of `:decimal`, is this the best choice?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's no specific type for *double*, Rails tries to be smart about it:

The numeric (integer/decimal/float) column definitions use the `:limit` option for the number of bytes in an integer column type, and the `:scale`/`:precision` options for floats.

(precision is the number of significant digits; scale is how many of these fall after the decimal point.)

Answer (score 26):

In my case (for test-db preparation):

MySQL (with mysql2(0.3.11) driver):

```
double(64,12)
```

Rails (in db/schema.rb):

```
   t.float :limit=>64                    ==> failed
   t.float :limit=>53                    ==> occasionally succeeded
   t.decimal :precision=>64, :scale=>12  ==> fully succeeded
```

Answer (score 8):

You can get Rails to create a `DOUBLE`. I'm not sure how "officially" supported the following solution is, but it works for MySQL.  Just set the limit to 53.  e.g.:

`t.float :published_at, :limit => 53, :null => true`

I got the answer from [this blog post](http://jblevins.org/log/rails-and-mysql-types) and there is some more testing results regarding this there.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, the limit is stripped off and not present in my schema.rb (Rails 4.0)

Answer (score 6):

I'm seeing a problem with this solution. If I have a declaration like this:

```
t.float :latitude, :limit => 30
```

everything looks great: the database schema shows the column is declared as a double. The problem is that schema.rb lacks any :limit value, so when the schema is cloned into the test environment, the column becomes a float rather than a double. Unit tests fail because there's not enough accuracy in the column.

If you look at the docs for ActiveRecord [column definitions](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-column) what you find is this:

> :limit - Requests a maximum column length. This is number of
>   characters for :string and :text columns and number of bytes for
>   :binary and :integer columns.

It's silent on the topic of floats. It appears from the code that it's a side effect of how :limit is supported that this solution works. It looks like either there's a bug in the generation of schema.rb or else it was never intended to be used this way.

I'm afraid the answer may be that the :decimal data type (which I don't care for) is the fully-supported solution.

Answer (score 3):

In modern versions of Rails (I'm using 5.1)

```
t.column  :field, "double"
```

Answer (score 1):

in your migration:

```
t.decimal :amount, precision: 32, scale: 16, default: 0, null: false
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue. After a lot of google and reading the rails docs I could not find anything helpful till I came across this post.

I fix this issue as [Stephen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/691416/stephen) suggested. Plus I added the parenthesis with the precision like this:

`t.column :cantidad, "double(6,3)"`

My rails version is: `Rails 6.0.3.2`

This is my migration:

```
class CreateDetalleVenta < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :detalle_venta do |t|
      t.column :cantidad, "double(6,3)"
      t.decimal :precio, precision: 11, scale: 2
      t.references :venta, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.references :producto, null: false, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

And after running the migration it generated this sql:

```
CREATE TABLE `detalle_venta` (`id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
`cantidad` double(6,3), `precio` decimal(11,2), `venta_id` bigint NOT NULL, `producto_id` bigint NOT NULL, `created_at` datetime(6) NOT NULL, `updated_at` datetime(6) NOT NULL,  INDEX `index_detalle_venta_on_venta_id`  (`venta_id`),  INDEX `index_detalle_venta_on_producto_id`  (`producto_id`), CONSTRAINT `fk_rails_166445d4ab`
FOREIGN KEY (`venta_id`)
REFERENCES `venta` (`id`)
, CONSTRAINT `fk_rails_c3914ce495`
FOREIGN KEY (`producto_id`)
REFERENCES `productos` (`id`)
)
```